# <audio> HTML5 doesn't work in Chrome but works in Edge

Tags: google-chrome, html5-audio

For some reason the audio element (attached below) shows up in Edge but not Chrome. I've tried adding and deleting control. The audio elements in the code below are at the very bottom. I added two of them just to see if it made a difference, and they both show up in Edge but not Chrome. I just can't figure it out. My Chrome browser is Version 70.0.3538.77. Thanks for reading this!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Hello Bulma!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.2/css/bulma.min.css">
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/js/all.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./helper.css">
</head>

<body>

  <section class="hero is-primary">
    <!-- Hero head: will stick at the top -->
    <div class="hero-head">
      <header class="navbar">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-brand">
            <a class="navbar-item">
              <span class="title">NAVARO</span>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div id="navbarMenuHeroC" class="navbar-menu">
            <div class="navbar-end">
              <a class="navbar-item">
                Home
              </a>
              <a class="navbar-item">
                Albums
              </a>
              <a class="navbar-item">
                Concerts
              </a>
              <span class="navbar-item">
                <a class="button is-primary is-inverted">
                  <span class="icon">
                    <i class="fas fa-headphones-alt"></i>
                  </span>
              <span>Listen</span>
              </a>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>
    </div>

    <!-- Hero content: will be in the middle -->
    <div class="hero-body">
      <div class="container has-text-centered">

        <!--Album-->
        <div class="center-column">
          <figure class="image is-128x128">
            <img src="./album_cover.jpg">
          </figure>
          <h2 class="title">
            Arctic Gibbons
          </h2>
          <h2 class="subtitle">
            NAVARO // Ft. Eric Clapton
            <br />
            <span>03.11.2018</span>
          </h2>
          <a class="button is-primary is-inverted">
            <span class="icon">
              <i class="fas fa-headphones-alt"></i>
            </span>
            <span>Listen</span>
          </a>
        </div>

        <!--Song Table-->
        <div class="container center-column" style="padding:25px">
          <table class="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Track</th>
                <th>Song</th>
                <th>Length</th>
                <th>Listen</th>
                <th>Buy</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
              <!-- Track 1 -->
              <tr>
                <th>1</th>
                <td>The View from the Afternoon</td>
                <td>3:19</td>
                <td>
                  <a class="button is-primary">
                    <span class="icon">
                      <i class="fas fa-headphones-alt"></i>
                    </span>

                  </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <a class="button is-primary">
                    <span class="icon">
                      <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
                    </span>
                    <span>Buy</span>
                  </a>
                </td>
              </tr>

              <!-- Track 2 -->
              <tr>
                <th>2</th>
                <td>I Bet You Look Good on the Dancefloor</td>
                <td>2:53</td>
                <td>
                  <a class="button is-primary">
                    <span class="icon">
                      <i class="fas fa-headphones-alt"></i>
                    </span>
                  </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <a class="button is-primary">
                    <span class="icon">
                      <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
                    </span>
                    <span>Buy</span>
                  </a>
                </td>
              </tr>

              <!-- Track 3 -->
              <tr>
                <th>3</th>
                <td>Fake Tales of San Francisco</td>
                <td>2:57</td>
                <td>
                  <a class="button is-primary">
                    <span class="icon">
                      <i class="fas fa-headphones-alt"></i>
                    </span>
                  </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <a class="button is-primary">
                    <span class="icon">
                      <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
                    </span>
                    <span>Buy</span>
                  </a>
                </td>
              </tr>

            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>

        <div class="container center-column">
          <audio src="https://www.bensound.org/bensound-music/bensound-dubstep.mp3" controls></audio>
          <p>the audio should exist above and below this element</p>
          <audio controls>
            <source src="https://www.bensound.org/bensound-music/bensound-dubstep.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
          </audio>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

  </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this seems to be a bug with bulma (or the underlying `minireset.css`):
https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/issues/2060.
There is also a pending pull request for this: https://github.com/jgthms/minireset.css/pull/15.

The minireset in bulma sets the `height` to `auto`, which overrides the user agent stylesheet and results in `0px`.

The CSS `revert` keyword should help here, but it is not supported (except in Safari): https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-revert-value.

If you want/can modify the bulma source in your project, you can "patch" the `minireset.sass` or `bulma.[min].css` according to the last commit of the mentioned pull request.